# Overloading operator new / allocate more than object size

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator

I'm trying to overloading the operator new of my class, I wanna allocate space for the objects' attributes and for a vector of chars that isn't defined in the class.

But when I instance an new object, the chars of previously object are changing.
Am I doing something wrong?

```
class StringData
{       
public:
    friend class String;
    int refCount;
    int len;
    int maxLen;
    ~StringData()
    {

    }
    StringData()
    {
        maxLen = 1000;
        len = 0;
        refCount = 1;
    }
    StringData(const char * string)
    {
        maxLen = 1000;
        char * data = buffer();

        len = 0;
        while (string[len] != '\0' && len < (maxLen - 1))
        {
            data[len] = string[len];
            len++;
        }
        data[len] = '\0';
        refCount = 1;
    }
    char* buffer()
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<char*>(this + 12);
    }

public:
    void* operator new(size_t size, int maxLen)
    {

        return ::operator new(size + round4(maxLen + 1));

    }
    static int round4(int len)
    {
        return ((((int) (len / 4)) + 1) * 4);
    }

    void operator delete(void* obj)
    {
        ::operator delete(obj); 
    }
    void operator delete(void* obj, int size) throw ()
    {
        ::operator delete(obj); 
    }
};
```

I use this in other class:

```
class String{
public:
    StringData * data;

    String(StringData * data){
        this->data = data;
    }
public:
    String(const char*);
    String(const String&);
    ~String();
    String& operator =(const String);
    String& operator =(const char *);
    int length() const;
    bool operator ==(const String&) const;
    int compare(const String&) const;
    bool operator ==(const char*) const;
    int compare(const char*) const;
    String& operator +(const String&) const;
    String operator +(const char*) const;
    String operator +=(const String&);
    String operator +=(const char*);
    String toLower();
    String toUpper();
    char operator [ ](int) const;
    char& operator [ ](int);
    void print() const;
```

};

```
String::String(const char * string){
int stringLen = 0;

while (string[stringLen] != '\0')
    stringLen++;

data = new (stringLen + 1) StringData(string);
```

}

```
String::String(const String& string){

data = string.data;
string.data->refCount++;
```

}

```
String::~String(){
this->data->refCount--;
if (this->data->refCount == 0)
    delete data;
```

}

```
String& String::operator=(const String string){
data->refCount--;
if (this->data->refCount == 0)
    delete data;
data = string.data;
string.data->refCount++;
return *this;
```

}

`void String::print() const{
    printf("%s\n", data->buffer());
}`

And my main function is:

```
int main(){
String *a = new String("boisahzashdacaraverdeepretaeazuleamarelaecinzaevermelha");
a->print();
String * s = new String("freestepehnoisquevoaashashashhasshashhasssasassadasd");
String * b = new String("kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk");

a->print();
s->print();
return 0;
```

}

When I execute, the strings are broken:

boisahzashdacaraverdeepretaeazuleamarelaecinzaevermelha

boisahzashdacaraverd

freestepehnoisquevoa

Comment: pls add tag with language

Comment: Can you show how you are testing this?

Comment: @BrunoGouveia: I suspect your operator new isn't being called at all... But without seeing the test-code for it, I can't say for sure.

Comment: `char& String::operator [ ](int);` is what makes reference-counted strings a bad idea.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Reference counted strings work great if they implement copy-on-write semantics, such as in a non-const `[]` operator. If a modifying operation detects that a string's reference count is greater than 1, it can allocate a new copy of the payload with a reference count of 1, update the string to point at that new payload, and decrement the reference count of the previous payload so other strings are not affected.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I know how COW works.  Do you know why a non-const `[]` makes COW a bad idea?  It does unnecessary copies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a great idea:

```
return reinterpret_cast<char*>(this + 12);
```

Not only does it fail if you ever add/remove some member functions [or make a virtual function], but it's also dependent on the size of `int`.

Use

```
return reinterpret_cast<char*>(this) + sizeof(*this);
```

[Note newplacement of the end of reinterpret_cast<>()!!]
The first version skips `12 * sizeof(*this)` forwards, rather than `12` bytes. 
[Of course, on my machine, when I used the 4* multiplier of maxLen, it actually works - it only began failing when I removed that]

This can be simplified:

```
((((int) (len / 4)) + 1) * 4);
```

Is this supposed to be 4 times larger than maxlen:

```
(4 * maxLen)
```

to:

```
4 * (len / 4 + 1);
```

I will be back with edits to this answer once I know the answer to the comment about how it is being tested.

Comment: Ready, I added how I'm testing.

Comment: Wait, `this + sizeof(*this)` and `this + 12` are both wrong aren't they?  Don't those advance 12 times the size of the object pointed to by `this`, for array iteration and whatnot?

Comment: @Mooing Duck: Yes, came to the same conclusion (just took me a little longer...)

Comment: This code is from my teacher... he wrote that in the class, and we have to continue deploy the class. It's a really naive mistake, and it's the first time that I see overloading new operator. Thank you guys... I lost my afternoon into this. kkkkkk

Comment: Well, obviously either you copied the code down wrong, or it was badly written by your teacher... Unfortunately, it's an easy mistake to make, but one that can be quite tricky to find...

Comment: @BrunoGouveia: which parts are teacher provided? The whole concept is silly, `String` should allocate a buffer and placement new `StringData` in the front :/

Comment: @MooingDuck: does that not make sharing strings [copy on write] a little difficult?

Comment: @MatsPetersson: `StringData` is part of the buffer, so not in this case.  It doesn't complicated copy on write any more than the original code.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Yeah, ok, I was more thinking of the case where you update the string, but I guess all the work ends up in `String` anyway, whether you allocate in `StringData` or `String`. Definitely agree that allocating in `String` makes more sense at the very least for trivial cases.

Comment: I have no idea what you just said.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I can be wrong, but if I allocate a buffer into string, i can't do things like I did in String& String::operator=(const String string) String::String(const String& string)

Comment: I don't copy the whole buffer into the copy constructor or operator =, I just make references of data